# how to test file server plugin on Symbian emulator?

Tags: file, plugins, symbian

I am developing a simple file server plugin that intercepts requests. I want to test it. Because of the TCB capabilities I can't put it on a real device. How can I test it on Symbian^3 emulator? I am new to platform developments. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the default setting for platform security in emulator, but at least you can turn off platform security enforcement by editing epoc.ini configuration file: http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Emulator/emulator-ref/EpocIniSyntax.guide.html

See specifically settings PlatSecEnforcement and PlatSecDisabledCaps.